# Vue.js route does not match even though it is defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to create a Vue SPA app. But the route does not seem to match what I have defined in my router. I can't understand why this is happening. As far as I see everything should be working. What am I missing here?

My index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New Vue.js Project</title>
        <script src="assets/js/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vue-router.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {{ 'Route: ' + JSON.stringify($route) }}

            <v-app>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </v-app>
        </div>

        <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js

```
import routes from './routes.js'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: routes,
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World!',
  },
})
```

My routes.js

```
import Index from './views/Index.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            name: 'index',
            path: '/',
            component: Index,
        },
    ],
})
```

When I navigate to http://localhost/new-vue-project/ and print {{ $route }} I get this:

```
{
   "name":null,
   "path":"/new-vue-project/",
   "fullPath":"/new-vue-project/",
   "matched": [

   ]
}
```

I also tried to add base property to my router but I got the same results.

```
base: 'http://localhost/new-vue-project/',
```

Comment: You did not define router for `/new-vue-project`

Comment: What do you mean? I created new VueRouter()...

Comment: But you only have `/` route, not `/new-vue-project`

Comment: The Vue app is inside the new-vue-project folder. I tried to set the base to it but it didn't match. base: 'http://localhost/new-vue-project/',

Comment: @TimothyLee oh, I see what you mean. My mistake was that I included 'http://localhost/' in my base path. When I used base: '/new-vue-project/' then it works as expected! Thanks!

Comment: Yes! set the base to `/new-vue-project/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `relative` path without domain name (localhost), according to the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base), like this:

```js
base: '/new-vue-project/'
```

Also it's possible to configure public path at `vue.config.js` file globally:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/new-vue-project/' : (process.env.VUE_APP_MY_APP_BASE_PATH || '/')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, using the correct base path without localhost worked. Note: I am not using cli/webpack so in this case I couldn't use vue.config.js